# Building for 10.5 in Xcode 3.2 (on Snow Leopard) error

Tags: xcode, osx-leopard, target

I just created a new Cocoa project on XCode 3.2. I'm running it in Snow Leopard.

When I build it for 10.6 it works fine but if I change the active SDK to 10.5 I get this error:

```
cannot find protocol declaration for 'NSApplicationDelegate'
```

Answer (score 33):

NSApplicationDelegate is a [new protocol as of 10.6](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSApplicationDelegate). You're getting the error (I'm guessing) because your application delegate is implementing this protocol. I'm not sure if this is the best practice on this, but you might just consider using the preprocessor to help you:

```
#if (MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED <= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_5)
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject
#else
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
#endif
```

Comment: If i compile for 10.5 I'm getting same error message in xcode

Comment: Ha, my bad. MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6 isn't defined on 10.5, so we have to keep the logic in terms of 10.5. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: Thanx this worked for me. Jorge you need to accept this answer!